# Very weird Python variable scope behaviour

Tags: python, arrays, function, scope

I'm having a problem with Python 2.7 that is driving me insane.

I'm passing an array to some functions and altough that variable is suposed to be local, in the end the value of the variable inside main is changed.

I'm a bit new to Python, but this goes against any common sense I got.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

```
def mutate(chromo):
    # chooses random genes and mutates them randomly to 0 or 1
    for gene in chromo:
        for codon in gene:
            for base in range(2):
                codon[randint(0, len(codon)-1)] = randint(0, 1)
    return chromo

def mate(chromo1, chromo2):
    return mutate([choice(pair) for pair in zip(chromo1, chromo2)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # top 3 is a multidimensional array with 3 levels (in here I put just 2 for simplicity)
    top3 = [[1, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1]]

    offspring = []
    for item in top3:
        offspring.append(mate(top3[0], item))

    # after this, top3 is diferent from before the for cycle
```

**UPDATE**
Because Python passes by reference, I must make a real copy fo the arrays before using them, so the **mate** functions must be changed to:

```
import copy
def mate(chromo1, chromo2):
    return mutate([choice(pair) for pair in zip(copy.deepcopy(chromo1), copy.deepcopy(chromo2))])
```

Comment: The likely short answer is that there are no "variables" in python, only "names", which basically means everything is pass-by-reference, even items in sequences.

Comment: @jbssm: Also, please don't use `from random import *`. This is considered bad practice for good reasons.

Comment: Thank you Niklas, I'll change that.

Comment: Actually, I still don't understand this... shouldn't `zip` and `choice` create new values?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Yes, I also don't understand why if I do the copies inside the **mutate** function the behaviour goes wild. For some reason I have to make the deepcopies in mate.
Perhaps because my Array is a 3D Array.
But to say the truth, this let me really down with Python. Data types and functions not being consistent acrod the board, some pass by reference, some make copies, it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Don't be silly. Everything is passed in the same way. It's perfectly possible to make sense of what's going on here; but do consider providing more context or doing at least a little debugging.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: You just asked 2 comments before: "shouldn't zip and choice create new values?" and then say it's silly that I think that not everything is passed in the same way. Now, that's a bit silly of you, don't you agree?
And I did debugging, in fact I did a lot of it, that's how I found that something was inconsistent in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You manipulate `chromo`, which you pass by reference. Therefore the changes are destructive... the `return` is therefore kind of moot as well (`codon` is in `gene` and `gene` is in `chromo`). You'll need to make a (deep) copy of your `chromos`, I think.

Comment: Thank you. So, I need to make a TMP copy in the **for** loop before calling the **mate** function, or in another place?

Comment: I'd create a copy in the mutate function so you can keep your structure, and the "return" becomes meaningful

Comment: Well, in the mutate, something strange came up: after a while, all my vectors would be the same.
So I moved the copy to the mate (using the `copy.deepcopy()` routine and it seems to be working correctly now.

Comment: @jbssm: "something strange came up ..." -- this set off a Red Flag for me. It sounds like you were getting unexpected results and rather than understand the problem and fix it you ... changed it to something else. If I read your comment correctly, then this is a *very* bad habit to get into. Any bug you simply FWITIW (F*ck with it til it works) is going to come back and bite you in the ass some day. This is 39 years of experience talking.

Comment: agree with peter, you might want to show the code that didn't work out. the reason I suggested copying in mutate and not in mate is that you're making one unnecessary copy now at each step (the one in zip that doesn't get choosen)

Comment: Perhpas it was my error, I'm not testing so troughly, but now this functions seems to be working correctly:`def mutate(chromo):
    # chooses random genes and mutates them randomly to 0 or 1
    chromoTmp = copy.deepcopy(chromo)
    for gene in chromoTmp:
        for codon in gene:
            for base in range(2):
                codon[randint(0, len(codon)-1)] = randint(0, 1)
    return chromoTmp`

Comment: yep nice that sounds like copying what must be copied ant nothing more!

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is stemming from the fact that arrays and dictionaries in python are passed by reference. This means that instead of a fresh copy being created by the def and used locally you are getting a pointer to your array in memory...

```
x = [1,2,3,4]

def mystery(someArray):
     someArray.append(4)
     print someArray

mystery(x)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]

print x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Ah, ok, so where should I make a copy of my array in the for loop? Like: `for item in top3:
top3_tmp=top3[0], itemTmp=item
        offspring.append(mate(top3_tmp, itemTmp))`

Answer (score 0):

try changing

offspring.append(mate(top3[0], item)) to 
offspring.append(mate(top3[0][:], item[:]))

or use the list() function

Comment: With the [:] it doesn't work. I'll see if I can do it with the list()